# Can't get the result after sending post data using requests in python

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping

I send POST data using the requests library in python.
I can't get the result of the form. I wonder it's because it's too fast.
The action URL of the form is the same page. And when I manually fill the form and submit it, then the result of the form appears at a div of the page. But when I use requests in python, the result div is empty even though the response status code 200. What should I do to obtain the result?

my code is below:

```
import requests
import time
from time import sleep

url = "https://******"

data = {
    'year': '1973',
    'month': '03',
    'name': 'chae'
}
res = requests.post(url, data)
print(res) #status code 200 
print(res.text)
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your request return JSON? If yes, you might try to use res.json() to fetch result

Comment: Most browsers have some debugging functionality to look at the communication between browser and server. Check if this communication is really that simple POST that you expect.

Comment: I can find the values of input form that I sent on the result page. But I still cannot see the result value after submitting the form. Do I have to press submit button? How can I do it on python?

Comment: https://www.efine.go.kr/licen/truth/licenTruth.do?subMenuLv=010100  
This is the page. And the blue color text is the result text.

Comment: Could you give us a valid data?

Comment: data = {
    'checkPage': '1',
    'flag': '',
    'regYear': '1973',
    'regMonth': '03',
    'regDate': '01',
    'name': '채승완',
    'licenNo0': '11',
    'licenNo1': '91',
    'licenNo2': '822161',
    'licenNo3': '12'
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code give me the information:

```
import requests
import time
from time import sleep

url = "https://efine.go.kr/licen/truth/licenTruth.do"

# data = {'checkPage': '1', 'flag': '', 'regYear': '1973', 'regMonth': '03', 'regDate': '01', 'name': '채승완',
#         'licenNo0': '11', 'licenNo1': '91', 'licenNo2': '822161', 'licenNo3': '12'}

data = {
    "checkPage": "2",
    "flag": "searchPage",
    "regYear": "1973",
    "regMonth": "03",
    "regDate": "01",
    "name": "채승완",
    "licenNo0": "11",
    "licenNo1": "91",
    "licenNo2": "822161",
    "licenNo3": "12",
    "ghostNo": "2161",
}
res = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(res.text)

# result contains "전산 자료와 일치 합니다.식별번호가 일치하지 않습니다."
```

Comment: The problem was flag parameter. Thank you so much!!! You made my day.

Answer (score 1):

try using `requests.Session()` instead of `requests`, it worked for me.

I've always did it this way, please check out this https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/ and let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: Tried requests.Session() as you adviced. But it didn't work unfortunately.